# Insert/submit new record not working on detailsview in insert mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, insert, detailsview, insert-update

I have a detailsview that is always in insert mode.  The user will always only enter new records never edit or view.  The probelm I am having is when i press the insert button(to add a new record after the fields have been filled out) nothing happens.  The record is not entered and the page shows no change.

I have been working on this detailsview for weeks and not made much progress because of these problems with postback and submitting values.  Any help is appreciated

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   if (!IsPostBack)
    {
       DetailsView1.DataBind();
    }
   }

protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
   {
     ObjectDataSource1.DataBind();
     DetailsView1.DataBind();
     SqlDataSource1.DataBind();
   }

protected void DetailsView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      TextBox employeeID = (TextBox)(DetailsView1.FindControl("TextBox17"));
      DropDownList approverID = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList4"));

      if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode == DetailsViewMode.Insert)
      {
        var CurrUser = "";

        Account.Login uusr = new Account.Login();
        CurrUser = uusr.User.Identity.Name.ToString().ToUpper();

        employeeID.Text = CurrUser.Substring(3, 3);

        string supusrid = "";

        DataHandler.DataHandler Dt = new DataHandler.DataHandler();
        supusrid = Dt.SelectRequestApproverForm(supusrid);

        approverID.SelectedValue = supusrid;
      }
  }

 protected void DropDownList6_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }

protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      DetailsView1.DataSource = null;
      DetailsView1.DataBind();
   }

protected void Button2_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Button3.Visible = true;
   }

protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      DetailsView1.Visible = true;
      DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
      if (DetailsView1.CurrentMode.Equals(DetailsViewMode.Insert))
        {
          Button3.Visible = false;
          Button4.Visible = false;
          DetailsView2.Visible = true;
          DetailsView3.Visible = true;
        }
   }

protected void DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }

protected void DropDownList6_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
   }

protected void DropDownList6_DataBound1(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
     DropDownList lvreason = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList5"));
     DropDownList lvtype = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList6"));
     //null reference to the object
     if (!IsPostBack)
       {
         string selectedValue = lvtype.SelectedValue;
         if (selectedValue == "4 " || selectedValue == "1F")
         {
              SqlDataSource1.SelectParameters["LEAVECODE"].DefaultValue = selectedValue;
              DetailsView1.Fields[4].Visible = true;
              lvreason.Visible = true;
         }
         else
         {
              DetailsView1.Fields[4].Visible = false;
         }
         lvtype.Items.Add(new ListItem("EDUCATION LEAVE"));
         lvtype.Items.Add(new ListItem("EXCUSED LEAVE"));
         lvtype.Items.Add(new ListItem("FUNERAL LEAVE"));
         lvtype.Items.Add(new ListItem("JURY DUTY"));
         lvtype.Items.Add(new ListItem("ON THE JOB INJURY LEAVE"));
         lvtype.Items.Add(new ListItem("PERSONAL HOLIDAY"));
         lvtype.Items.Add(new ListItem("SICK LEAVE"));
         lvtype.Items.Add(new ListItem("VACATION LEAVE"));
      }
  }

protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
  {
     DropDownList lvtype = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList6"));
     DropDownList lvreason = (DropDownList)(DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList5"));
     if (lvtype.SelectedValue != "")
     {
       if (lvtype.SelectedValue == "3 ")
       {
         lvreason.Text.Equals("VACATION").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
         lvtype.Text.Equals("VACATION").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
         //DetailsView1.Fields[4].Visible;
        }
        else if (lvtype.SelectedValue == "1E")
        {
          lvreason.Text.Equals("EDUCATION LEAVE").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
          lvtype.Text.Equals("EDUCATION LEAVE").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
        }
        else if (lvtype.SelectedValue == "1N")
        {
          lvreason.Text.Equals("ON THE JOB INJURY LEAVE").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
          lvtype.Text.Equals("ON THE JOB INJURY LEAVE").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
        }
        else if (lvtype.SelectedValue == "1J")
        {
          lvreason.Text.Equals("JURY DUTY").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
          lvtype.Text.Equals("JURY DUTY").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
        }
        else if (lvtype.SelectedValue == "1X")
        {
          lvreason.Text.Equals("EXCUSED LEAVE").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
          lvtype.Text.Equals("EXCUSED LEAVE").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
        }
        else if (lvtype.SelectedValue == "1P")
        {
           lvreason.Text.Equals("PERSONAL HOLIDAY").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
           lvtype.Text.Equals("PERSONAL HOLIDAY").ToString().Trim().ToUpper();
        }
     }
  }
```

aspx code:

```
<td class="style2" colspan="2">
  <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" 
  DataSourceID="ObjectDataSource1" DataKeyNames="requestid"
  Height="29px" Width="928px" AutoGenerateRows="False" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333"
  GridLines="None" Style="margin-right: 0px; text-align: left; margin-top: 0px;" 
  ondatabound="DetailsView1_DataBound" 
  onitemcommand="DetailsView1_ItemCommand" 
  oniteminserting="DetailsView1_ItemInserting" >
     <Fields>
      <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Request ID" HeaderText="Leave Request ID" Visible="False">
        <EditItemTemplate>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("requestid") %>'></asp:Label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox165" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("requestid") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("requestid") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Employee ID" HeaderText="Employee ID" >
        <EditItemTemplate>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("emppid") %>'></asp:Label>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox17" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("emppid") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("emppid") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Approver ID" HeaderText="Approver ID">
        <EditItemTemplate>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList4" runat="server" style="text-transform:uppercase;" DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceApprover"
           DataTextField="APPROVNAME" DataValueField="APPROVERID" SelectedValue='<%# Bind("approverid") %>'>
          </asp:DropDownList>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("approverid") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Leave Type" SortExpression="reqleavecode">
        <EditItemTemplate>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
          <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList6" runat="server" Height="20px"
          onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList6_SelectedIndexChanged" Width="171px" 
          ondatabound="DropDownList6_DataBound" AutoPostBack="True" 
          SelectedIndex='<%# bind("reqleavecode") %>'>
           <asp:ListItem  Text="-- SELECT LEAVE --" Value ="-1" Selected="True"></asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1E">EDUCATION LEAVE</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1X">EXCUSED LEAVE</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1F">FUNERAL LEAVE</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1J">JURY DUTY</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1N">ON THE JOB INJURY LEAVE</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="1P">PERSONAL HOLIDAY</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="4 ">SICK LEAVE</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem Value="3">VACATION</asp:ListItem>
          </asp:DropDownList>
          <asp:Label ID="Label26" runat="server" Text='<%# bind("reqleavecode") %>'></asp:Label>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label9" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("reqleavecode") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Leave Type" HeaderText="Leave Reason" Visible="False">
         <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("leavetype") %>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
         <EditItemTemplate>
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <InsertItemTemplate>
           <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList5" runat="server" AppendDataBoundItems="True" 
           AutoPostBack="True" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="REASON" 
           DataValueField="REASON" Height="19px" 
           onselectedindexchanged="DropDownList5_SelectedIndexChanged1" 
           SelectedValue='<%# Bind("leavetype") %>' Width="163px">
           </asp:DropDownList>
           <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1Reason" runat="server" 
           ControlToValidate="DropDownList5" ErrorMessage="*Leave Reason Required" 
           ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>
      <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="start date" HeaderText="Leave Date">
       <EditItemTemplate>     
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <InsertItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lstdate",  "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' Height="21px"
         Width="67px"></asp:TextBox>
         <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox5_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox5">
         </asp:CalendarExtender>
         <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" 
         ControlToValidate="TextBox5" ErrorMessage="*Leave Date Required" 
         ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
         <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator18" runat="server" 
         ControlToCompare="TextBox7" ControlToValidate="TextBox5" 
         ErrorMessage="Leave date cannot be after start date" ForeColor="Red" 
         Operator="LessThanEqual" ToolTip="Must choose start date before end date"></asp:CompareValidator>
       </InsertItemTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label7" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lenddate") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="lenddate" HeaderText="Return Date">
        <EditItemTemplate>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox7" runat="server" 
          Text='<%# Bind("lenddate",  "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}") %>' Height="21px"
          Width="67px"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:CalendarExtender ID="TextBox7_CalendarExtender" runat="server" Enabled="True" TargetControlID="TextBox7">
          </asp:CalendarExtender>
          <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator3" runat="server" 
          ControlToValidate="TextBox7" ErrorMessage="*Return Date Required" 
          ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
          <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
          ControlToCompare="TextBox5" ControlToValidate="TextBox7" 
          ErrorMessage="Return date cannot be before start date" ForeColor="Red" 
          Operator="GreaterThanEqual"></asp:CompareValidator>
       </InsertItemTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lsttime") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
          </asp:TemplateField>
          <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Leave Time" HeaderText="Leave Time">
       <EditItemTemplate>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <InsertItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox15" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lsttime") %>' Width="85px"
          Height="22px" ToolTip="Type 'A' or 'P' to switch AM/PM"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="TextBox15_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox15"
          Mask="99:99" MaskType="Time" AcceptAMPM="True" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" 
          CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder="" 
          CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" 
          CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True" />
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator1" runat="server" 
          ControlToValidate="TextBox15" ErrorMessage="*Invalid Time" ForeColor="Red" 
          ValidationExpression="^((([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]((:|\.)[0-5][0-9])?( )?(AM|am|aM|Am|PM|pm|pM|Pm))|(([0]?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]((:|\.)[0-5][0-9])?))$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
        </InsertItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lendtime") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Return Time" HeaderText="Return Time">
        <EditItemTemplate>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <InsertItemTemplate>
          <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lsttime") %>' Width="85px"
          Height="22px" ToolTip="Type 'A' or 'P' to switch AM/PM"></asp:TextBox>
          <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="TextBox8_MaskedEditExtender" runat="server" 
          AcceptAMPM="True" CultureAMPMPlaceholder="" CultureCurrencySymbolPlaceholder="" 
          CultureDateFormat="" CultureDatePlaceholder="" CultureDecimalPlaceholder="" 
          CultureThousandsPlaceholder="" CultureTimePlaceholder="" Enabled="True" 
          ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" Mask="99:99" MaskType="Time" 
          TargetControlID="TextBox8" />
          <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidator10" 
          runat="server" ControlToValidate="TextBox8" ErrorMessage="*Invalid Time" 
          ForeColor="Red" ValidationExpression="^((([0]?[1-9]|1[0-2])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]((:|\.)[0-5][0-9])?( )?(AM|am|aM|Am|PM|pm|pM|Pm))|(([0]?[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(:|\.)[0-5][0-9]((:|\.)[0-5][0-9])?))$"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
       </InsertItemTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
          <asp:Label ID="Label10" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("standby") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Standby" HeaderText="On Standby">
       <EditItemTemplate>
       </EditItemTemplate>
       <InsertItemTemplate>
         <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource10"
         DataTextField="&quot;Y/N&quot;" DataValueField="&quot;Y/N&quot;" SelectedValue='<%# BIND("standby") %>'>
         </asp:DropDownList>
       </InsertItemTemplate>
       <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rsndecline") %>'></asp:Label>
       </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Reason Decline" 
         HeaderText="Request Decline Reason" InsertVisible="False">
      <EditItemTemplate>
      </EditItemTemplate>
      <InsertItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox12" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("rsndecline") %>' Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
      </InsertItemTemplate>
      <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:Label ID="Label13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>'></asp:Label>
      </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="Status" HeaderText="Request Status" InsertVisible="False">
         <EditItemTemplate>
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <InsertItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox13" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("status") %>' Visible="False"></asp:TextBox>
         </InsertItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="Label14" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("empremarks") %>'ToolTip="Additional information pertaining to leave request"></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
       </asp:TemplateField>
       <asp:TemplateField AccessibleHeaderText="empremarks" HeaderText="Leave Request Remarks">
         <EditItemTemplate>
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <InsertItemTemplate>
             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox14" runat="server" style="text-transform:uppercase;" Text='<%# Bind("empremarks") %>' 
             TextMode="MultiLine" Height="47px" Width="452px" 
             ToolTip="Additional information pertaining to leave request."></asp:TextBox>
         </InsertItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
           <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
           CommandName="Edit" Height="21px" Text="Edit" Width="65px" />
           <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
            CommandName="New" Height="21px" Text="New" Width="65px" />
         </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
         <EditItemTemplate>
         </EditItemTemplate>
         <InsertItemTemplate>
             <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" Text="Submit Request" />
             <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
             CommandName="Cancel" Height="21px" onclick="Button2_Click1" Text="Cancel" />
         </InsertItemTemplate>
         <ItemTemplate>
             <asp:Label ID="Label5" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("lstdate") %>'></asp:Label>
         </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>
       </Fields>
     </asp:DetailsView>
   </td>
 </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="style2" colspan="2">
                            <asp:Button ID="Button3" runat="server" Height="21px"  onclick="Button3_Click" 
                                Text="With Pay Leave Request" />
                        &nbsp;&nbsp;
                            <asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" Height="21px"  onclick="Button4_Click" 
                                Text="Without Pay Leave Request" style="margin-left: 13px" Width="221px" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
            ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent %>" 
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT REASON, LEAVECODE FROM LEAVRSN">
            <SelectParameters>
                <asp:Parameter Name="LEAVECODE" Type="String" />
            </SelectParameters>
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SQLLEAVECODE" runat="server" 
           ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent %>" 
           ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent.ProviderName %>"                
           SelectCommand="SELECT LEAVETYPE, LEAVECODE FROM LVTYPE ORDER BY LEAVECODE">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceApprover" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT APPROVERID, APPROVNAME FROM APPROVER ORDER BY APPROVERID">
        </asp:SqlDataSource>

        <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource10" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent %>"
            ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionStringEvent.ProviderName %>" 
            SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM YNSELECT ORDER BY ALPH"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1111" runat="server">

        </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                <br />
                <asp:Label ID="Label17" runat="server" ForeColor="#999999" 
                    Text="Exhibit B PP-8"></asp:Label>
                <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server" DeleteMethod="DeleteRequestForm"
                    InsertMethod="InsertRequestForm" SelectMethod="SelectRequestEMPID" TypeName="DataHandler.DataHandler"  
                    UpdateMethod="UpdateRequestFormLastName" OldValuesParameterFormatString="original_{0}">
                    <DeleteParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="requestid" Type="Int64" />
                    </DeleteParameters>
                    <InsertParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="requestid" Type="Int64" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="emppid" Type="Decimal" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="leavetype" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="lstdate" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="lenddate" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="lsttime" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="lendtime" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="standby" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="rsndecline" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="empremarks" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="approverid" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="reqleavecode" Type="Int32" />
                    </InsertParameters>
                    <SelectParameters>
                       <%-- <asp:Parameter Name="emppid" Type="Decimal" />--%>
                       <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="emppid" QueryStringField="emppid" Type="Decimal" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                    <UpdateParameters>
                        <asp:Parameter Name="requestid" Type="Int64" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="emppid" Type="Decimal" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="leavetype" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="lstdate" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="lenddate" Type="DateTime" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="lsttime" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="lendtime" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="requesreason" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="standby" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="status" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="rsndecline" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="empremarks" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="approverid" Type="String" />
                        <asp:Parameter Name="LASTNAME" Type="String" />
                    </UpdateParameters>
                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                            <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource2" runat="server" 
                                SelectMethod="SelectNameEmployeeForm" 
                                TypeName="DataHandler.DataHandler">
                                <SelectParameters>
                                    <asp:Parameter Name="empid" Type="Decimal" />
                                    <asp:Parameter Name="firstname" Type="String" />
                                    <asp:Parameter Name="lastname" Type="String" />
                                </SelectParameters>
                            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
                <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
                </asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
        <asp:Label ID="Label27" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
    </asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try and remove the other `DataBind()` methods in your `ItemInserted Event handler`. I believe you only want to `DataBind()` the detailsview.

Answer (score 0):

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      if (!IsPostBack)
      {
        DetailsView1.DataBind();
      }
   }

delete this   DetailsView1.DataBind();

Comment: Please add code formatting to your code (indent with 4 white-spaces) and write some text to explain/support your code.